# Cut doesn't work on particular angles view

Tags: edit-mode, edges

I got a strange issue tonight. When i cut edges under a narrow angle it works well, but when i do it from the top view (perpendicularly), it doesn't show me the cut marker point (but it still cuts). Could anyone give me a clue how to solve it?

[image: OK]

[image: Marker point is invisible]

Comment: I've noticed that sometimes the knife seems to "catch" on geometry clipped by the camera. Try setting the camera start clipping to 0, or switching to perspective when you can.

Comment: @SilverRain Thanks for your tip, switching to perspective view solved the problem - i am able to select any of the edges now. BTW setting start clipping to 0 does some strange stuff: https://i.imgur.com/cyTrvel.png and makes blender almost unusable - when I try to zoom the model out, it throws me far away from it:)

Comment: Another clue - this can be caused by the clipping tool (Alt+B) i use to see the internal part of my model

Comment: If I add that as an answer, will you accept it?

Comment: @SilverRain Sure! That is a pretty good solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not too tough to solve this problem by switching to perspective view. This helps keep the knife from "catching" on geometry that you cannot see.